# Node Backend Setup (Multiple Node App or just One Universal Node App?

Tags: node.js, mern

I am trying to create back-end with nodes and it will have three clients. 
- Mobile App
- Web App
- Admin Panel

I heard that the node is a single thread app. To have maximum performance is it better to have three node servers or just one that connects all? I am using MERN stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question doesn't have a single answer and could possibly be considered opinion based.

However, the ultimate choice of your architecture - wheter you will have a single app that serves the backend for multiple frontends or multiple separate apps for each frontend - doesn't really depend on performace considerations and is completely independent on the fact that node is single threaded or not.

It's because, regarding scalability and performance, you will possibly use the cluster module to scale your app to multiple processor cores and then, you will have a farm of servers processing incoming requests. This holds regardless of your architecture.

If I were you, I'd have a single application supporting multiple frontends from the single backend then. Assuming you can correctly control the access to the backend (so that for example, web users are not able to forge requests and interfere with the mobile app), a single app could possibly be easier to deploy.